# How to remove lower margin from UI-Boostrap Angular Tab directive?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The ui.bootstrap.tabs directive found [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) has an inherit margin before it displays it's content.

[image]

HTML:

```
<uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="false" id="tabSet" style="background-color: red">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Assessment" class="uib-tab">
        <p style="background-color: green">TEST</p>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" headin[![enter image description here][2]][2]g="SJ" class="uib-tab"></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Long Justified" class="uib-tab"></uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

The `<uib-tabset>` has `background-color: red` to show this margin.

My CSS won't stop it. (Perhaps it's a property I don't know of?)

```
.uib-tab {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.uib-tabset {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Any ideas to try? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the css you are trying to apply is on the correct element, I would suggest increasing the specificity of the selector such as "#tabSet .uib-tab", or use !important.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the style applied to the p element in the tab content.  The tab-content and tab-pane classes (which are applied to the elements wrapping the tab content) have no margin or padding styles.  This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/S0kvTWBJrHVoSNACPmiN?p=preview) demonstrates the effect you are seeing.  The code I used to prove this is:

```
<uib-tabset active="active" style="background-color: red;">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="Tab 1">
    <div style="background-color: green;">Tab 1 content</div>
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="1" heading="Tab 2">
    <p style="background-color: blue;">Tab 2 content</p>
  </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="3" heading="Tab 3">
    <p style="background-color: yellow; margin: 10px;">Tab 3 content</p>
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```